# How to do http get requests from Google Apps Script sidebar or dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, get, google-apps-script-addon

I'm trying to do a https GET request to my server from Google Sheets sidebar (or dialogue window). That is from a client-side. However, the following error is returned:

[image]

If there is any way how to directly communicate with my server's end-point?

P.S. A workaround is to do requests to Google Apps Script, which does UrlFetch and then returns data to the client-side, but this reduces the speed.

Many thanks!

Comment: Look at “client to server communication” in the guide section of the documentation.  Specifically look for “google.script.run”

Comment: Related [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247483/1595451)